# Swift | View sizes and fonts are different in different screen sizes

Tags: ios, swift

I have a big application with many screens. All of a sudden, every new screen I create has different sizes depending on the iPhone.

For example, I develop the app on an iPhone 12 Mini simulator and everything looks great. But, when I run the app on a physical iPhone XR, every button, every image, and every label is significantly smaller!

Everything has a static size. Eg a button with a static size of (80, 30). Note, that not every screen has this issue.

Any idea on what's going on?

Comment: Have you taken pixel density into account  (x1, x2, x3)? https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/icons-and-images/image-size-and-resolution/

Comment: But the issue is not only with images but with buttons, fonts, etc.

Comment: There's not nearly enough information here for us to help you. Can you show the code for a specific view that's showing this behavior and the code you use to lay it out?

Comment: First don't give height n width to any component.
Give leading trailing top and bottom constraints and also use content compression resistance, content hugging priority.